# How to add an extra link to the excerpt in wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, custom-fields

I'm trying to get this link to look like this:

Comment on this show >> | Listen to this show >>

Where "Comment on this show >>" gets populated properly with its permalink.

"Listen to this show >>" link should be populated with that posts 'Listen Now' custom field value.

```
function holylandmoments_comment_link() {
return ' <a class="read-more-link" href="'. get_permalink() . '">' . __( 'Comment on this show &raquo;', 'holylandmoments-show' ) . '</a> &nbsp;|&nbsp; <a class="read-more-link" href="'. get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Audio File',true); . '">' . __( 'Listen to this episode &raquo;', 'holylandmoments' ) . '</a>';
}
```

Problem is I don't get the path to the custom field value of Listen Now to populate the second link... any ideas??

The custom field value is a link to an audio file. So for all posts that fall under the category shows there is a custom field named 'Audio File' the value of that field is:

http://www.mydomain.org/audio/sample.mp3

So when the excerpt is called for archive pages to display I need two links to display one that points back to the post and another that points to the MP3 file.

So in my functions.php file I have the function above and then I call it with:

```
function holylandmoments_custom_excerpt_more( $output ) {
if ( has_excerpt() && in_category( _x('devotionals', 'devotionals category slug', 'holylandmoments') ) &&! is_attachment() ) {
    $output .= holylandmoments_read_more_link();
}
else
if ( has_excerpt() && in_category( _x('shows', 'shows category slug', 'holylandmoments') ) &&! is_attachment() ) {
    $output .= holylandmoments_comment_link();
}
return $output;
}
add_filter( 'get_the_excerpt', 'holylandmoments_custom_excerpt_more' );
```

Thanks!

Matt

Comment: The reason I am trying to do this is I need to create a podcast for iTunes and when I try to submit the feed to iTunes I keep getting errors saying that the feed has no episodes.

So I think adding the second link to the end of my excerpt iTunes will be able to find the path to the audio file and allow iTunes to pick up the episode.

Here is the link to my feed:
http://feeds.feedburner.com/HolyLandMoments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra semicolon in there.

```
href="'. get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Listen Now',true); . '">'
                                                    ^
```

Change to:

```
href="'. get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Listen Now',true) . '">'
```

The `$post` variable may not be in the current scope, so try bringing in the global `$post` into it.

```
function holylandmoments_comment_link() {
   global $post;
   return ' <a class="read-more-link" href="'. get_permalink() . '">' . __( 'Comment on this show &raquo;', 'holylandmoments-show' ) . '</a> &nbsp;|&nbsp; <a class="read-more-link" href="'. get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Audio File',true); . '">' . __( 'Listen to this episode &raquo;', 'holylandmoments' ) . '</a>';
}
```

I believe the function `the_ID()` also returns the ID of the current post, so try the following if it the other one doesn't work:

```
function holylandmoments_comment_link() {
   return ' <a class="read-more-link" href="'. get_permalink() . '">' . __( 'Comment on this show &raquo;', 'holylandmoments-show' ) . '</a> &nbsp;|&nbsp; <a class="read-more-link" href="'. get_post_meta(the_ID(), 'Audio File',true); . '">' . __( 'Listen to this episode &raquo;', 'holylandmoments' ) . '</a>';
}
```

Comment: This did not work... when I add this to the function the link that is generated links to the same page that the link is in.

Comment: @Matthew: I'm not exactly sure what you mean. Could you add an example of a link that is generated, versus what you expect/want?

Comment: @Daniel here is the link where I want these links to live:http://www.holylandmoments.org/shows

Comment: @Matthew: But where is an example of the 'Listen Now' link the code currently generates? Also, thanks, whoever downvoted me for no apparent reason :/.

Comment: @Daniel, since this site is live I don't want o keep up very long. I will repost the functions.php file so you can see what happens.

Comment: @Matthew: Is the `$post` variable set? It might not be in the scope when it's called. Try checking if it exists and then printing out the result. You could always define that function in the archive template and use it directly.

Comment: In my archive template I have:


<?php
   /* Run the loop to output the posts.
    * If you want to overload this in a child theme then include a file
    * called loop-index.php and that will be used instead.
    */
    get_template_part( 'loop', 'archive' );
   ?>

Comment: So i'm not sure where else I can make sure this is being set

Comment: @Matthew: Maybe if you add this as the first line to the `holylandmoments_comment_link` function: `global $post;`. I edited it into my answer so you can see.

Comment: @Daniel... great let me try this and I will get back to you.